# VB.NET - Click on DataGridView hyperlink and get text that was clicked on

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, hyperlink

I am creating a web application in asp.net and vb.net, I have a datagridview and a hyperlink column, but I want the hyperlink text that is clicked on to be stored as a session variable. Not sure how to do this so I don't have any code for it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: We can help, but we help with current problems that have been provided. `I don't have any code for it`, understand, but without any code how are we supposed to provide any help without anything to go on? Right now, this is broad, please update your post with an attempt.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I understand that this is a broad question, the thing is that I am not sure where to start! I would be very appreciative if I was pointed in the right direction